# I am trying to figure what went wrong with my hash. I am getting a error 'hash values do not match' as a soap response

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to figure what went wrong with my hash. I am getting a error 'hash values do not match' as a soap response.

The server log actually complains abt this hash value? Digest Value

```
     <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
              <Reference URI="#_1">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>l6kqP048t5INzJT3W8gxVSXplaE=</DigestValue>
              </Reference>

So Now I am trying to compare this DigestValue  with my code computed hash. 
Not sure how else I could try to fix this
```

1) Navigate to this element. Can I do this GetBytes?

```
 XmlNode xmlnodeSigDigestValue = dc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/s:Envelope/s:Header/o:Security/sig:Signature", nsmgr).ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[2]";
 string sSourceData = xmlnodeSigDigestValue.FirstChild.Value;//brings me to l6kqP048t5INzJT3W8gxVSXplaE
 byte[] tmpHash = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sSourceData);
```

2) This is the actual content of my request. So it is encrypting this and signing

```
 string ToCompare = @"ISA*00*00*ZZ*400034 *ZZ*100000 0507*1750*^*00501**IL*1*PELEYTAY*JAVIER~REF*SY*5~DMG*D8*1981*M~DTP*291*RD8*20130115-20130115~EQ*30~SE*14*0001~GE*1*456452~IEA*1*526208405~";
byte[] tmpNewHash;
tmpNewHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(tmpSource);
bool bEqual = false;
if (tmpNewHash.Length == tmpHash.Length)
{
    int i=0;
    while ((i < tmpNewHash.Length) && (tmpNewHash[i] == tmpHash[i]))
    {
        i += 1;
    }
    if (i == tmpNewHash.Length) 
    {
        bEqual = true;
    }
}
```

Can I compare these two?. Am I understanding it correctly?
How else would I compare hash?

Comment: Language choice goes in the tags, not the title of your question.  Signatures aren't necessary; your ^^--signature card is already displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the time u've taken to edit my question.. Would you mind answering the question?

Comment: I don't know the answer.  Maybe someone else here does.

Comment: Hash values do not match.. Signer status: 'Extracted the certificate chain from the BinarySecurityToken having format x509. 'Hash values do not match. My server has a chain cert, user cert is not a chain. Encryption is done using server and signed using usercert.. Would this be a problem with the private key in usercert\